# React redux testing by logging on console without a front end rendering part

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am learning React redux and I am completely new to its workflow. Although I have significant experience with `Haskell`, `Javascript`, and some experience with `node.js` type web dev. I am following this doc: https://redux.js.org/basics/store, in the section Dispatching Actions, I see this bit of code:

```
import {
  addTodo,
  toggleTodo,
  setVisibilityFilter,
  VisibilityFilters
} from './actions'
​
// Log the initial state
console.log(store.getState())
```

Suggesting I could log to the console without UI. I am confused because where would I log to console if I am not running a GUI? As I understand all of `react` is running on client side, so where would I call `index.js` to run it? My directory currently is like this:

```
src
    App.tsx
    todo
        actions.tsx
        reducer.tsx
        index.tsx      <--- this is where the console.log would be
```

More broadly, I am asking about an equivalment to a `repl` development workflow to `react redux`. For example I do log to console using vanilla `js` and `node`, even though there may be better options, it's a matter of comfort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` index.tsx to a component being rendered, in your case, import to App.tsx

for example:

```
//index.tsx

const testLog = (message) => {
  window.console.log(message)
}
export default testLog
```

then on App.tsx assuming its a stateful component:

```
// App.tsx

import * as React from 'react'
import TestLog from './todo/index'

class App extends React.PureComponent {
  public componentDidMount(){
    TestLog('hello')
  }
  public render(){
    return(
     <div>test</div>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

You can also use `global.console.log()` on TypeScript

Answer (score 1):

I was going to write a comment but it got bigger so here it is as an answer.

It logs to browser's web developer console. Docs would be not so clear but actually you are using a javascript file there and use it in some html file and inspect it with your browser.

So, when you console.log, you have a GUI and see the result in your dev tools console. Obviously you need to use getState() where your store created and that file must be run somehow.

I suggest you watching those two tutorials from the creator of Redux. They are great and let you understand what is under the hood of Redux and how things get glued together.

[Getting Started With Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux)

[Building React Applications with Idiomatic Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/building-react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux)

If you are so new to React first go without Redux, then after digesting React go for Redux. As a learner and not so much experienced with Javascript, I've learned quite a bit with this order.

Answer (score 1):

There are several places you can check your redux logs.

1. Using reducer
   You will have a function called a reducer where the dispatches hits. So eigther you can log your dipatches.
2. mapStateToProps
   The first parameter of this function is the value of state in the store. So any changes to the store will be available to this function when you connect a component with this function.
3. middleware
   You can add a middleware using applymiddleware function to the store while its getting created. 
   You can check out [redux-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-logger) an npm module which uses this layer.